# Maven release: avoid checking out the whole branch

Tags: git, maven, deployment, nexus, maven-release-plugin

I am developing big modular solution, which is stored under single GIT repository. That's becomes a huge problem, when deploying separate components to Nexus.

E.g. to deploy new version of tiny scirpt, I have to checkout the whole branch. But logically this script belongs to the project, so it would be impractical to store it in a separate git repo.

Is there solution to this problem?

Comment: Its not "that" impractical. I did exactly this on my project. Now we, after correctly dealing with dependencies, can deploy or rebuild just a portion of the solution, w/o checking out/rebuilding all the project. Its not like heaven, but way better than handle everything all the time.

Comment: It'll result in many "technical" repositories in Stash. Total mess. As I understand, if talking about Maven/Git, then REPOSITORY=DEPLOYMENT UNIT. Which is absolutelly irrational in my opinion.

Comment: What do you mean by `big`? How large is your git repository (size?) ? and how long does it take to do a `git co BRANCH`?

Comment: ~1G, while script size is ~100K

Comment: 1G? do you have binaries into your repository? I mean, a lot of big binaries...

Comment: @vratojr Got your point. Yep, unfortunatelly we have binaries in repo. I believe it's time to think of cleaning it up.

Comment: Yeah...:) If you extract the binaries and clean the history of your repo as shown in https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data, and maybe putting the binaries in another repo, your problem should solve.

Comment: @vratojr Could you convert your comment into an answer so I can vote it up.

Comment: A part from the problem of the size of repository, I'm not quite sure what you problem is... I mean, you have a big project, that supposedly includes subprojects inside itself (since you build separate components) and you would like to avoid checking out the whole project for just a small modif?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a big repository, if you extract the binaries and clean the history of your repo as shown [here](http://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data), and maybe putting the binaries in another repo, your problem should solve.